# Интеграция Google sheets со своим api

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Фактически требуется взять данные из api и вставить их в определённые клетки таблицы. Есть ли такой функционал, что бы взять данные из первых двух клеток, допустим, и как в формулу передать данные в api и в клетку или клетки вставить ответ от api?